# Sending jQuery colorbox color to an additional element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send the selected jQuery colorbox color chosen by user to a a text string inside

```
<div class="user-text">
```

Currently it is only affecting the display sxwatch that shows what the user is selecting.
Here is the function I am trying. I figured I could just add a new line telling it the display 'color'.

```
$('.user-text').css('color', '#' + hex);
```

Here is the entire function I have

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
color: '#0000ff',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
},
onHide: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
},
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    $('.user-text').css('color', '#' + hex);
}
  });
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? Does the color not return correctly? What line is the error?

Comment: Im not getting any errors, but the string of text inside <div class="user-text"> is not changing to the user selected color.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you need the `html()` method

```
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    $('.user-text').css('color', '#' + hex);
    $('.user-text').html('Your chosen color: #' + hex);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work. Here is my entire code so far if that helps? The <div class="user-text"> gets inserted into the dom via the form field "enter your own text" http://neocenturymedia.com/external_files/logo/demo.html   it's the "choose a custom text color that isn't working"